# How to make a button in an animated SubView work during movement of that SubView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

In the following code, the subView with button oscillates  i.e. moves horizontally from origin point to red area and back.

But it does not receive clicks on the button itself, instead it receives clicks on the red area.

[image]

I want to make this button in an animated SubView work during movement of that SubView on x axis only.

Being at beginner level of this technology, I got stuck-up here.

Below is the code of .h and .m files respectively.

*ViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIView *viewWithButton;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *viewWithButton;
- (void) animateButton;

@end
```

*ViewController.m*

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize viewWithButton;

- (void) animateButton
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

    CGPoint pos = viewWithButton.center;
    pos.x = 400;
    viewWithButton.center = pos;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
- (IBAction)btn
{
    NSLog(@"Button Tapped");
}
```

Comment: I believe you cannot interact with a button while it is animating. try using NSTimer and set the buttons frame.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
Will try this now..

Comment: do have single button or multiple?

Comment: @MohitPopat I just have a single button on the subview which is animated. it does not preform animation outside the area of same size with 400 center...
I dont have enough reputation points to provide u guys with the screenshot.

Comment: i gave it to you for your both question. enjoy now

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will help you. take one array and add your button to that array.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrBtn;
[self.arrBtn addObject:btn];
```

make animation something like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:8.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){   
                 }];
```

add this method to get touch

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    for (UIButton *button in self.arrBtn)
    {
        if ([button.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchLocation])
        {
            // This button was hit whilst moving - do something with it here
            NSLog(@"button title is %@",button.titleLabel.text);
            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
            NSLog(@"Button Clicked");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: finally got an upward which allowed me able to upload the screen shot... Thanks man
I hope u guys might get clear idea from the screen shot now.

Comment: I dont know why but for loop is now getting access in this code

Comment: no, i even get the touchLocation but nothing more than that.

Comment: what is the problem now?

Comment: did you get this log NSLog(@"Button Clicked");?

Comment: The button with the gray colored view is animating from its current position to the red View location as shown in the screen shot, But it receives touches from the whole view screen.

Comment: did you get this log NSLog(@"Button Clicked");?

Comment: no, for loop is not getting access while execution. Even tried keeping break point

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52426/discussion-between-piyush-mathur-and-mohit-popat)